# Cypress: How to Login during beforeEach

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, mapping, cypress

```
beforeEach('Login', function() 
{
cy.visit('/')
    
const userCred = new Map(users);    
for (const [key, value] of userCred.entries()) 
{
    
        cy.login(key,value)
    })
}
})
```

I get following error Message
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xKU.png
[![error message][1]][1]

The Login Command works when I use it in the `describe ('login', ()=> { it('login', ()=>{ cy.login(key, value) })})`

How can I get the login work in the beforeEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you mess synchronous and asynchronous code.
Here is how you should do it:

```
for (const [key, value] of userCred.entries()) {
    beforeEach(function() {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.login(key, value);
    })
}
```

Also, I would recommend you to put `cy.visit('/')` inside the `login` custom command, as:

1. `.login()` cannot be called without it;
2. you are not repeating yourself on every test;